# DROP All Views PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, view, dynamic-sql, sql-drop

How I can Delete All User Defined Views From PostgreSQL using a Query? 
Like we can delete All functions using query :

```
SELECT 'DROP FUNCTION ' || ns.nspname || '.' || proname 
       || '(' || oidvectortypes(proargtypes) || ');'
FROM pg_proc INNER JOIN pg_namespace ns ON (pg_proc.pronamespace = ns.oid)
WHERE ns.nspname = 'my_messed_up_schema'  order by proname;
```

Answer (score 6):

Script for deleting all views in a certain schema:

```
SELECT 'DROP VIEW ' || t.oid::regclass || ';' -- CASCADE?
FROM   pg_class t
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.relnamespace
WHERE  t.relkind = 'v'
AND    n.nspname = 'my_messed_up_schema -- select by schema(s)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The cast to [`regclass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) (`t.oid::regclass`) prevents [SQLi](http://bobby-tables.com/), because otherwise illegal names are quoted automatically. You could also use `quote_ident()`.

Your example is inherently unsafe.

[**`Do`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) it right away:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   sql text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO sql
          string_agg('DROP VIEW ' || t.oid::regclass || ';', ' ')  -- CASCADE?
   FROM   pg_class t
   JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.relnamespace
   WHERE  t.relkind = 'v'
   AND    n.nspname = 'my_messed_up_schema';

   IF sql IS NOT NULL THEN
      -- RAISE NOTICE '%', sql;  -- to debug
      EXECUTE sql;
   ELSE
      RAISE NOTICE 'No views found. Nothing dropped.';
   END IF;
END
$$
```

`DO` requires PostgreSQL 9.0 or later.

The `IF` construct avoids an exception if no views are found.

If you have views referencing other views, you'll have to add the keyword [`CASCADE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-dropview.html) or drop views in their hierarchical order from top to bottom.

*Always* check what you are going to drop before you do it, or you might nuke yourself. If you are unsure, start a transaction, drop the bomb, check if all is good and then either commit or roll back.

```
BEGIN;
DO$$
  ...
$$;

-- check ..

ROLLBACK; -- if something wrong
COMMIT; -- else
```

Note that you cannot `COMMIT` or  `ROLLBACK` *inside* the plpgsql block. Only outside.

Comment: Works, as long as there are views to drop, but causes an error if there are no views. How can I fix that? What form of `execute` is that which you use? In the manual I only found this in conjunction with `prepare`...

Comment: @yankee: That's plpgsql code inside the `DO` block, so ***not*** the SQL command to execute prepared statements. I added a version that catches the exception. [Find related questions here.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A939860+%5Bplpgsql%5D+%5Bdynamic-sql%5D+execute)

Answer (score 0):

Use table [`pg_class`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html).

You need `relkind = 'v'`

Comment: how to escape out System Views From this pg_class. I want only views that belongs to particular schema

Comment: @SatishSharma `pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace ns ON c.relnamespace = ns.oid WHERE ns.nspname = 'my_messed_up_schema'` Same as in your example.