# Syntax error on Truncate SELECT table_name

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I'm using PostgreSQL and I try to truncate all tables starting with `'beach'`.
In other words I would like to do something like:

```
Truncate (SELECT table_name
          FROM information_schema.tables
          WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name LIKE 'beach_%')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use truncate that way.

Comment: You would need to create dynamic SQL statement string and execute them.

Comment: `beach` or `bridge`? I unified your example.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid syntax. You can't use `TRUNCATE` with a sub-query (see [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-truncate.html)). Further, you probably need [a procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) that iterates through these tables and truncates them.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading the [manual on `TRUNCATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-truncate.html) for instructions on proper syntax.

Next, you are looking for **dynamic SQL**, since you cannot use wilcards or patterns for table names in `TRUNCATE`. You need to compose the SQL command dynamically. You can do this in *two* round-trips to the server like has been advised, or you can use a single [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) statement:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN

EXECUTE (
-- RAISE NOTICE '%', (   -- better check before you execute ..
   SELECT 'TRUNCATE ' || string_agg(c.oid::regclass::text, ', ')
   FROM   pg_class c
   JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
   WHERE  c.relname LIKE 'beach_%'
   AND    c.relkind = 'r'
   AND    n.nspname = 'public'
   );

END
$do$;
```

Creates and executes a command of the form:

```
TRUNCATE beach_foo, beach_bar, ...
```

You may want to / have to add `CASCADE` at the end of the command.

Related answer:
[DROP All Views PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643831/drop-all-views-postgresql/13653683#13653683)

Consider the subtle differences between **information schema** and **system catalogs**:
[How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

You may or may not want to query `information_schema.tables` instead. Most importantly ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/infoschema-tables.html)):

> Only those tables **and views** are shown that the current **user has access**
>   to (by way of being the owner or having some privilege).

Bold emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could run this query

```
SELECT 'truncate ' || table_name || ';'
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_name LIKE 'beach%'
```

This will return a row like

```
truncate someTableName;
```

for each table starting with beach.

Copy the result set, paste it, and execute it.

See this [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2d88a/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you would go about it by creating dynamic SQL:

1. Create the string to truncate
2. Execute the string using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Read here..

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ecpg-dynamic.html

Answer (score 0):

At the end I tryied this

```
     ResultSet resultSet=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_name LIKE 'beach_%'");
     while (resultSet.next()) {
         list_tables.add(resultSet.getString("table_name"));
    }
     for (String table : list_tables) {
         stmt.executeUpdate("TRUNCATE "+table); 
    }
```

and it works fine